# Angular 4 : AWS SDK

Tags: angular, aws-sdk-js

I'm facing an issue with Angular 4, I'm building my first Angular app who is using the Amazon SDK. So far so good, I'm able to get responses from Amazon and I'm able to print them in the console.

The issue I have is that I'm unable to show the data in my view because the getData function does not wait for the checkTags function.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
getData(){
//I'm fetching all my db instances
this.DataService.getData().subscribe(data => {
 for(let i = 0; i< data.length; i++)
 {
   //I'm fetching all my tags for each instance
   //This function give me back a db object
   //Db {insDBInstanceIdentifier: "abc", DBInstanceStatus: "stopped", DBInstanceClass: "db.t2.micro", DBInstanceArn: "arn:aws:rds:eu-west-1:826d95599:db:abc", managed: "true"}
   //this db object will later be put in an array, so we can loop through it
  console.log(this.checkTags(data[i]));
  this.dataOutput = this.checkTags(data[i])

 }
  return this.dataOutput;
});


checkTags(data_input){

   this.DataService.getTags(data_input["DBInstanceArn"]).subscribe(data => {
       this.managed = false;
          for(let i = 0; i <data.length; i++)
          {
              if(data[i]["Key"] == "managed")
              {
                this.managed = data[i]["Value"];
              } 
          }
          this.db_obj =  new Db(data_input["DBName"],data_input["DBInstanceStatus"],data_input["DBInstanceClass"],data_input["DBInstanceArn"], this.managed  );
          console.log(this.db_obj)

  return this.db_obj;
```

});

Comment: use binding data to the component

Comment: Hi Roman, thanks for the suggestion, can you give me a small code example? I've tried out some changes but I still don't see anything.

Comment: In my view, I want to loop through these dynamic values